# Ruby global variables, legitimate uses

Tags: ruby

I've never seen global variables used in any Ruby code.  I understand that their use is frowned upon across languages but they seem actually *useless* in Ruby.  Can anyone point to properly designed code that uses them?

If I'm right and they're redundant/historical, why do they persist in 1.9?

To be clear, I don't mean variables that Ruby sets up for you like `$"` and `$stdin`. I mean uses in one's own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time I see it in decent code is for a log.

```
$log = Logger.new('foo.log', 'daily')
```

A constant would probably do fine, but it somehow feels strange calling methods on a constant.

Comment: "class methods" is an example of calling methods on a constant.

Comment: I suppose the Rails equivalent of your $log is Rails.logger, a cattr_accessor. I suppose they're functionally equivalent to global variables, so they're not so unusual after all!

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are usually Global variables in Ruby.
So are CLASSPATH in jruby and so on...

Also, you can implement cheap singletons using global variables (although it's not advisable).

So, global variables definitely have a place in Ruby.

Comment: +1 Global variables have their, although limited and rare, use in any language.

Comment: That's an interesting point about creating singletons or rather, objects that need to be initialised at most once in the live of the program. Those would typically be referenced via SomeConstant though rather than `$some_global_variable`.